# Unable to remove Python3.5

Tags: python, python-3.6, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

My machine has both python3.5 and python3.6 installed in the base environment.
I had to remove python3.5 because of some reasons.
I tried removing it by command - `sudo apt-get remove python3.5`and `sudo apt-get purge python3.5`.

It shows python3.5 is removed from the system. But when I run some program using python3.5 it is still running.

How to remove python3.5 completely from the machine ?

Comment: Well, it's a Debian based system.   `dpkg -l|grep python 3.5` you might want to `apt purge ...` those.  So those programs have a #!/usr/bin/python3.5 she-bang line?  What does `which python3.5` say?

Comment: Don't do this! A lot of services require the python interpreter to work. I did it once and it rendered my pc useless...

Comment: @AllanWind it is showing /usr/bin/python3.5 and after doing `dpkg -l|grep python 3.5` it is showing some standard python3.5 libraries

Comment: @Djib2011 python3.6 is there in the system.

Comment: I'm second with @Djib2011 - don't mess with python installed system-wide. Just forget about it's existence if you're are not developing ubuntu distribution itself. Learn to use virtual envs.

Comment: `dpkg -S /usr/bin/python\*` will tell you what package that binary comes from.  python3.5-minimal would be my guess.  If you removed it, let's see if it's a symlink `ls -l /usr/bin/python3.5`

Comment: He already (claimed to have) removed them.  Purging will just get rid of left over stuff.  Also, I am not asking him to remove all python files just that particular version.

Comment: @AllanWind `-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4460304 Oct  9 22:25 /usr/bin/python3.5` Looks like it is not symlink

Comment: What did the dpkg -S command tell you?

Comment: @AllanWind yes It is python3.5-minimal

Comment: Is that installed? `dpkg -l|grep  python3.5-minimal`.

Comment: Why do you still use Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @AllanWind Yes. It is showing

Comment: @guettli I am running in some server. I can't just go and change

Comment: Well, now it's up to you... you can try to remove it, and address the dependencies, or leave it be (as others warned you about :-)).  The programs you have that use 3.5 might have updated versions against later python releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You remove python3.5-minimal (as root) with:

```
apt remove python3.5-minimal
```

Review the output to ensure you are cool with dependencies also being removed before proceeding.